# Setar atributo de uma outra classe Python

Tags: python, python-3.x, django

Eu estou estudando python e gostaria de entender como posso definir um atributo de uma classe com base em atributos de outra classe.

Eu vou para o exemplo para ficar mais claro, é apenas um exemplo do que preciso para minha pequena aplicação django, onde no cadastro de uma pessoa, irei setar o cargo dela com base nos cadastros de cargos.

```py
    {class Pessoa(models.Model):

    nome = models.CharField(max_length=20, null=False)
    cargo = ##abrir opções de Cargos cadastrados em "Cargos"


class Cargos(models.Model):

    nome_cargo = models.CharField(max_length=20, null=False)}
```

Comment: Nesse link tem uma explicação sobre os relacionamentos do Django: [Relacionamentos de Tabela DJANGO](https://www.treinaweb.com.br/blog/relacionamento-1-1-1-n-e-n-n-com-django/)

Comment: Você quer uma classe em outra classe?

Comment: @MauryDeveloper oi, consegui resolver, na verdade era um relacionamento, respondi a pergunta pois consegui entender aqui, Obrigado

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Pessoa deve ter um relacionamento com Cargo, que nesse caso, é um relacionamento 1,n. O Django usa o ForeignKey para esse tipo de relacionamento.

```
class Pessoa(models.Model):
    nome = models.CharField(max_length=20, null=False)
    cargo = models.ForeignKey('Cargos', on_delete=models.CASCADE)


class Cargos(models.Model):
    nome_cargo = models.CharField(max_length=20, null=False)}
```